# height 100vh и лишние пиксели

Tags: html, css

При использовании `height:100vh;` выдает какую-то лишнюю высоту. даже `box-sizing:border-box;` не помогает

```css
.vh100 {
background:red;
height:100vh;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="vh100"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никаких лишних пикселей.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.vh100 {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="vh100"></div>
```

С учетом `padding` и `margin`:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.vh100 {
  background: red;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="vh100"></div>
```

Comment: Однако посмотрите, вы убрали все паддинги и марджины. А как сделать так чтобы они тоже существовали но не влияли на высоту

Comment: Это конечно хорошо,но можно ли обойтись без "Магических Чисел"

Comment: @eenigmage что вы подразумеваете под "магическими числами"?

Comment: 40px. ведь у них может быть разный размер

Comment: @eenigmage `100vh` вам всегда выдадут `100%` высоты `viewport`. а какие отступы и поля вы потом будете использовать - ваше дело. Просто, учитывайте их в `calc(100vh - XXpx)`